# swift - implement the func to change background color for the whole screen for multiple tabs

Tags: swift

my app has 04 tabs, i want to write a func to change the background color for the whole screen: status bar, naviation bar, etc.

i want this because when i change color in the func then the whole app will change

below i just change to the top. but too complicated

what i have done is change the status bar text to white

```
    //change text of status bar to white
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {

    return .lightContent

}
```

go to the Storyboard, Select the View Controller and in the Editor menu Select Embed in Navigation Controller. Select the Navigation Bar and in the Attribute Inspector set the Bar Tint color to red.

in appDelegate.swift

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .blackOpaque
    return true
}
```

[image]

Comment: In each of the viewControllers `viewDidLoad()` functions you'll want to change the view's properties.

Comment: i wanna create a common func and call in any viewControllers

Comment: @Apper.ml You could make a `CommonViewController` (example name only) that's a subclass of `UIViewController`, and a superclass of all of your VCs

Comment: As @Alexander suggests is good solution still you have another option is to create `protocol`  and create extension of this protocol for self == ViewController and add a method there and call it from viewDidLoad wherever you want to call